# Installing PHPNG from source on Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: php, osx-mavericks, gnu, bison

I'm installing php-ng from source:

https://wiki.php.net/phpng

```
configure: error: bison is required to build PHP/Zend when building a GIT checkout!
```

I have bison installed so I don't understand

```
bison (GNU Bison) 2.3
```

I have also installed bison using homebrew this installs version 3.0 but for some reason it's still using version 2.3 (not sure if this is an issue?) and my **/usr/local/bin** appears before my **/usr/bin** (strange one) Brew says my system is ready and raring to brew.

Hope someone can help,

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve this by copying over the brew bison located here into /usr/bin not sure why brew didnt handle this?

Comment: You can accept your own answer also. Removes the question from the unresolved queue...

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use YACC env variables to specific that.

```
YACC=/path/to/bison ./configure (---args)
```